# yii2 : How to have ip check range validation in create and update form

Tags: php, yii2

I have two tables

```
labels (id , name, mask, subnetID, ...)
ip (id , ip, labelID[foreign key], ...)
```

in my labelsController I have :

```
    public function actionCheckrange($id,$ip){
    $ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
    $iptolong = ip2long($ip);
    $label = $this->findModel($id);
    $netID = $label->netID;
    $mask = $label->mask;
    $range = $this->findIpRange($netID, $mask);
    if( $iptolong <= $range['lastIP'] && $iptolong >= $range['firstIP'] ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>".
            "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>".
            "IP is not in range".
            "</div>";
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Also I can return $range['firstIP'],$range['lastIP'] as well and in my IpController :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Ip();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $label = $model->label;

        if ($model->save())
        {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'OK');
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
        }  else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Error');
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

in my IP form :

```
        <?= $form->field($model, 'ip')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'language' => 'fa',
        'options' => 
            [
                'placeholder' => 'انتخاب IP' ,
                'dir' => 'ltr',
                'onchange' => '$.post("/labels/checkrange/"+$("#w0").val()+"?ip="+$(this).val(),function(data) {
                                        $("#range-warninig").html(data);
                                    });'
            ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'dropdownAutoWidth'=>true,
            'tags' => true,
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

In "IP" _form user first choose the range(Label) and then ip-address , we should check this ip exists in the selected range!
The question is how can I check the ip-adress is in the selected range(label) and prevent user to create IPs that not exist in selected range?

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in [IP validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-ipvalidator.html) with range validation option.

You can find out more about model validation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html).

Comment: I read this before!! Actually I want to check range based on selected ip range ("label"). We cant use model validator like ['ip_address', 'ip', 'ranges' => ['192.168.0.0/24']]!!!!!!!!! I should validate ip by POST requested cidr!!!!

Comment: So, your question is how to decide if an IP address is in a specific range?

Comment: In "IP" _form user first choose the range and then ip-address , we should check this ip exist in the selected range!